# Java getTimeZone() behaving differently for different kind of inputs

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst

For the below code I get different outputs

```
TimeZone t = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8");  // Also tried UTC-8 and GMT-8:00
//TimeZone t = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d = null;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(t);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
d = c.getTime();

String s = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(s + "        " + t.inDaylightTime(d));
```

Output is:

```
08/22/2013      false
```

Now *America/Los_Angeles* is GMT-8 / UTC-8 or PST. But when I change parameter from GMT-8 to *America/Los_Angeles*,

Output is:

```
08/22/2013      true
```

Can't use PST like abbreviations since its deprecated. Also CST can mean both *Central Standard time* and *China Standard Time*.

The input I have is like -8, -9 -14 etc. to which I wish to prepend GMT/UTC to know if I can get the DST activation on a given date.

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Isn't it expected? You can't guarantee all location under GMT-8 have DST. DST is regulated differently by each country / state government.

Comment: Java TimeZone has a list of available Ids(getAvailableIDs()) like America/Boise
America/Cambridge_Bay,America/Chihuahua,America/Dawson_Creek
America/Denver,America/Edmonton,America/Hermosillo
America/Inuvik,America/Mazatlan,America/Ojinaga
America/Phoenix,America/Shiprock,America/Yellowknife  which is random, not all cities are covered here (Example Boston, Washington).So how do I be sure to get daylight info using limited options

Answer (score 3):

The results are correct, when you specify `GMT` with an offset there is no way to know which country/city is this, so it is not possible to determine if `Day Light Time` is active or no.

So `inDaylightTime()` will be `false` for all time zones specified with `GMT` and an offset.

`CST` in Java is `Central Standard Time`, you can check yourself by this line of code:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST").getDisplayName());
```

`China Standard Time` zone ID in Java is `CTT`

**Edit**

Consider using *[Joda time and date API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)* for more up-to-date `Timezone` information

Comment: TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST") which is deprecated.

Comment: Yes it is better to use full name especially for `inDaylightTime` to work

Comment: You mean <i>     TimeZone t =TimeZone.getTimeZone("Central Standard Time");     </i>? This I don't think is supported.

Comment: No it will not work, I mean to use the full zone name e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25061/discussion-between-nixsix6-and-itech)

Answer (score 1):

The results are correct, as explained by @iTech. Just to add, you can lookup the timezone ids available as

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] timezones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        System.out.println(timezones.length);
        for (String t : timezones) {
            System.out.println(t);  
        }
    }
}
```

This prints a long list of 600 timezones available.

You can then get the display name for the abbreviated ones as

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST").getDisplayName());
```